# package.json for global node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am not able to find the package.json for global node modules. Where is this global package.json file found? If it does not exist, how does node.js keep track of global node modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no global package.json

`npm` doesn't keep track of globals, really. It just installs them in a common `node_modules` folder.

The binary or command file for the module is symlinked into an executable folder. for example, on my mac, the symlinks point to `/user/local/bin`

To install a global module, use the `-g` option when installing.

*for example*:

`npm install -g express-generator`

This will install the express-generator module into the global npm `node_modules` folder, and create the needed symlink to execute the `express` command line tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In this case, what is the recommended way to configure global packages? For example, I have Standard JS install globally for linting. There are some settings I'd like to add for Standard JS. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've added to my local package.json for now, which has the benefit of being shared with others, but has the disadvantage of being repeated per project for something that seems more global.